# Connecting to MS SQL Server in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, php-5.4

I'm running a WAMP stack and and trying to connect to an SQL Server instance with PHP's PDO.

I've downloaded the PHP drivers for MS SQL from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098) and added `**php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll**` into PHP's extension folder.

Then added "**php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll**" to the list of extensions in php.ini.

I know I'm using the correct driver because I'm using PHP version 5.4.3 and `**phpinfo()**` reports that it's thread-safe.

However, after restarting Apache `**phpinfo()**` (and `**PDO::getAvailableDrivers()**`) both report that only the mysql, odbc and sqlite PDO drivers are loaded.

This means that when I attempt to connect to my SQL Server instance I get the error:

```
could not find driver
```

Can anyone advise on how to get this working?

Comment: Did you restart Apache after making that change?

Comment: When you made those changes....you reboot the server, right??

Comment: Yes I did - sorry for not including in description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the SQL Native Client is missing.

> ## System Requirements
>
> Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client available in the SQL Server 2012 Feature Pack.

Comment: I installed this but PHP still reports that neither the sqlsrv or the out-dated mssql drivers are present. That said, it's not the simplest of packages to identify - could you please provide a link to ensure I'm using installing the right thing?

Comment: You will try to google the correct way of installing sql server drivers (one example http://robsphp.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/how-to-install-microsofts-sql-server.html)

php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll 
are you sure, you've selected the correct dll file? I thinks this one is for a VC9 built of apache.